# How to create array variable from variable string

Tags: php, arrays, variables

How to create variable from text in this situation:

```
$option["b"] = 'text';

$a['field'] = 'option["b"]';
```

this do does not work:

$x = ${$a['field']};

in this case the result is null, but variable $x value should be 'text'

Comment: One option is to parse the `option["b"]` string into a $arrayName string (`"option"`) and a $key string (`"b"`), then use `$x = ${$arrayName}[$key]`. But perhaps there's another way that I'm unaware of – so only commenting for now.

Comment: This solution works, hope there is easier one

Comment: *"does not work..."* - yes, because you don't have a variable named `option["b"]`. You have a variable named `option` which has a key `b`. Sounds like a bad idea to begin with. What practical scenario do you need this for?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I think you can do this by text is without the key. You can assign the array variable via a string, but not the key itself:

```
$option['b'] = 'text';

$var = "option";
$next = $$var; //variable variable which reads string as variable name
$a['field'] = $next['b'];
```

If you give me an example that expresses the purpose for this, I can probably come up with a function that does what you need.